# Alinear divs con un ícono usando Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Quiero poder alinear estos dos `div` en una misma linea, y a su vez, entremedio de estos dos, poder agregar un ícono.

Aquí una imagen de como me gustaría que quedara:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="card mb-4">
              <div class="card-header">
                <small class="form-text text-muted">
                    <i class="fas fa-tools"></i> Details  
                </small>
              </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="font-weight-light text-sm-left" style="margin-bottom: 0rem;"></p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 select-outline mb-2">
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Price</small>
                            <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="txt_fl" id="txt_fl" readonly> <i class="fa fa-equals float-right"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-1 select-outline mb-2">
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">&nbsp; Total</small>
                            <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="txt_fl_result" id="txt_fl_result" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Si alguien tiene alguna forma de hacer esto u otra solución agregando un span seria útil.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bootstrap ofrece múltiples clases de utilidad para trabajar con [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox). Aquí te dejo una tabla con algunas de ellas mostrando la propiedad y el valor que aplicarán:

```
┌────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬────────┐
│ Clase Bootstrap    │ Propiedad             │ Valor  │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼────────┤
│ d-flex             │ display               │ flex   │
│ flex-column        │ flex-direction        │ column │
│ flex-grow-1        │ flex-grow             │ 1      │
│ align-items-center │ align-items           │ center │
└────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴────────┘
```

Teniendo esto en cuenta, puedes crear una columna entre las columnas de los `inputs` con las siguientes clases:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">&nbsp,</small>
    <i class="fa fa-equals d-flex flex-grow-1 align-items-center"></i>
</div>
```

Lo que creará un contenedor con `display flex` y dirección de columnas. Al situar dentro del mismo (y antes del ícono) un elemento con las mismas clases que los `labels` de los inputs pero con un texto vacío, lograremos que el ícono quede en el espacio creado por la altura de los inputs. Y si al contenedor del ícono le aplicamos `flex-grow` con valor `1` y `align-items` con valor `center`, lograremos que el mismo ocupe el alto restante y que sus elementos (en ese caso el `::before` que contiene el ícono) queden centrados en la vertical:

> He eliminado múltiples elementos, propiedades y clases para hacer el ejemplo más conciso y que se pueda ver claramente el cambio.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Price</small>
      <input class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <small class="form-text text-muted">&nbsp,</small>
      <i class="fa fa-equals d-flex flex-grow-1 align-items-center"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Total</small>
      <input class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: buena respuesta solo con bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks my budda! funciono muy bien

Comment: Gracias @the-breaker.
¡Me alegro que te sirva de ayuda @MoteCL!

Comment: de nada @ElChiniNet y pensar que encontré la pregunta abandonada con 0 votos.

Answer (score 7):

Para lograr lo que buscas solo debes trabajar los estilos.

Dentro del `div row` puedes emplear tus propias clases en lugar de las de boostrap, por ejemplo puedes tener esta estructura:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="formularios">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Price</small>
    <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="txt_fl" id="txt_fl" readonly> 
  </div>
  <div class="igual">
    <i class="fa fa-equals"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="formularios">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">&nbsp; Total</small>
    <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="txt_fl_result" id="txt_fl_result" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Luego puedes asignar estilos por porcentajes, asegurándote que todo sume en total 100%:

```
  .igual{
    width: 2%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .formularios{
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
```

Si tienes el div igual que vale 2% y 2 divs formaularios que valen (45+2+2)% entonces

```
(2 + 49*2)% = 100%
```

También puedes asignarle un margen superior al igual para que este al centro con

```
margin-top: 30px;
```

Y así ya se muestra como quieres:

```css
.igual{
    width: 2%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .formularios{
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
          <small class="form-text text-muted">
            <i class="fas fa-tools"></i> Details  
          </small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="font-weight-light text-sm-left" style="margin-bottom: 0rem;"></p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="formularios">
              <small class="form-text text-muted">Price</small>
              <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="txt_fl" id="txt_fl" readonly> 
            </div>
            <div class="igual">
              <i class="fa fa-equals"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="formularios">
              <small class="form-text text-muted">&nbsp; Total</small>
              <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="txt_fl_result" id="txt_fl_result" readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfecta la respuesta, muy completa como siempre. Pero no crees que con las clases de Boostrap basta? Teniendo el framework no creo que sea necesario añadir más CSS.

Comment: @JheymanMejia claro, solo respondí una forma simple de resolverlo.

Answer (score 4):

Podrías lograr algo bastante parecido sin crear nada nuevo así:

- Hay que tener que la [`grilla de Bootstrap`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#grid-options) se divide en 12 columnas, por lo que podríamos decir que `Price` y `Total` podrían ocupar `5` cada una y el `=` podría ocupar `2`.
- Para que el `=` quede centrado, podemos agregar un `<small form-text>` vacío y utilizando un `<button disabled` para agregar el icono con `Font-Awesome`

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
          <small class="form-text text-muted">
            <i class="fas fa-tools"></i>
            Details  
          </small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="font-weight-light text-sm-left" style="margin-bottom: 0rem;"></p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 select-outline mb-2">
              <small class="form-text text-muted">Price</small>
              <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="txt_fl" id="txt_fl" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2 select-outline mb-2 text-center">
              <small class="form-text text-muted">&nbsp;</small>
              <button class="btn" readonly disabled><i class="fa fa-equals"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 select-outline mb-2">
              <small class="form-text text-muted">&nbsp; Total</small>
              <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="txt_fl_result" id="txt_fl_result" readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```